# Get a read-only view of a RcppArmadillo matrix

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I'm writing something that requires a lot of successive sub-views of a matrix to be used recursively. The views are only being read, so I'd like to just pass a reference to the submat to save the space.

Is this something that is possible in RcppArmadillo?

Comment: Yes it is, see the documentation.

Comment: So submat returns a reference to the original matrix?

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  Do you talk about R to C++, or C++ to C++?  Do you understand that R uses SEXP types which are **always** pointers, but lightweight?

Comment: I understand the R to C++ bit, I'm curious about C++ to C++.

Comment: Ok, then it becomes "easier" in the sense that everything is well-understood C++ semantics.  See Conrad's Armadillo documentation for all gory details.